# Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error

Tags: xcode, xcode4.4

### I am hitting an Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error when trying to compile https://github.com/kineme/AudioTools in 10.8 with Xcode 4.4.

I think its running into problems trying to import the "SkankySDK" which is available here: https://github.com/kineme/QCPatchXcodeTemplate

I used their install script to copy the frameworks into the system library.

I have imported the Framework into the project (It is in my **Build Phases** under **Link Binary With Libraries**, and I have also tried adding it to a new "Copy Files" build Phase to no avail)

The Framework is in my project under **Frameworks and Libraries > Linked Frameworks**

```
Ld build/AudioTools.build/Development/AudioTools.build/Objects-normal/i386/AudioTools normal i386
    cd /Users/tenkai/Desktop/Projects/QuartzComposer/AudioTools
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/tenkai/Desktop/Projects/QuartzComposer/AudioTools/build/Development -L/Users/tenkai/Desktop/Projects/QuartzComposer/AudioTools/Frameworks -F/Users/tenkai/Desktop/Projects/QuartzComposer/AudioTools/build/Development -F/Users/tenkai/Desktop/Projects/QuartzComposer/AudioTools -F/Users/tenkai/Desktop/Projects/QuartzComposer/AudioTools/Frameworks -F/Users/tenkai/Desktop/Projects/QuartzComposer/AudioTools/Frameworks/SkankySDK.framework/Headers -F/Users/tenkai/Desktop/Projects/QuartzComposer/AudioTools/Frameworks/SkankySDK.framework -filelist /Users/tenkai/Desktop/Projects/QuartzComposer/AudioTools/build/AudioTools.build/Development/AudioTools.build/Objects-normal/i386/AudioTools.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker "@loader_path/../Frameworks" -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -dead_strip -fobjc-link-runtime -framework SkankySDK -framework Cocoa -framework Quartz -framework CoreAudio -framework Accelerate -framework AudioToolbox -framework QuickTime -o /Users/tenkai/Desktop/Projects/QuartzComposer/AudioTools/build/AudioTools.build/Development/AudioTools.build/Objects-normal/i386/AudioTools

ld: framework not found SkankySDK
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you added the framework to your project's dependency list?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an adhock solution:

https://github.com/2mc/AudioTools

You do not even need to add the SkankySDK to the project, if you know where it is located. Mine is at the default location of /Library/Frameworks. So i added it to the search path for frameworks.

Then the file 'AudioEmbeddedFilePatchUI.xib' was still missing to build the project. However, just excluding it from the target allows the project to be build and it seems to work, still ;-).